# UIView with rounded corner and white border has outline, how to get rid of the outline

Tags: ios, uiview

I created a UIView with red background color, and a white border of 1pt width with following code.:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 20, height: 20))
self.view.addSubview(myView)
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
myView.layer.borderWidth = 1
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

But the myView rendered with a red outline, how to get rid of it? A enlarged screenshot is attached.

[image: Below is the enlarged screenshot]

Comment: Can you try this on a real device and check if it happens there?

Comment: @SaurabhYadav Tried on real device, still have the outline

Comment: Try myView.clipToBounds = true and pass borderWidth as 1.0

Comment: @vivekDas Tried, but not work

Answer (score 0):

It's not answer of your question

But you can make it better if you create another view and add it as a subview to your main view:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 20, height: 20))

let redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))


redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
myView.layer.borderWidth = 1
redView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
redView.layer.borderWidth = 1

myView.addSubview(redView)
self.view.addSubview(myView)

myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
myView.clipsToBounds = true
```

And result will be:

[image]